# Need to move small JSON messages from Kafka to HDFS with Kakfa Connect but without using Confluent libs, if not completely free

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'd like to use Kakfa Connect to move JSON messages from Kafka to HDFS and then Impala, only using OpenSource libs.

I was trying to understand if I can use the Confluent Sink library for Kakfa Connect, without the need to use the entire Confluent distribution.

Are there are other and/or better options to achieve this?

Comment: Nifi would work for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Kafka Connect HDFS 2 Sink](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-hdfs/current/index.html) is available under the [Confluent Community Licence](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq/). It is a plugin for Apache Kafka; you do not have to run Confluent Platform to use it.

Comment: OP might be referring to the HDFS3 sink

Comment: What does OP mean?

Comment: "Original Poster", i.e. you :-)