# What open source solutions exist to move data from Kafka to HDFS3 using Kafka Connect?

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

Other than the Confluent HDFS library (not open-source), is there any completely open-source library to move messages from Kafka (using Kafka Connect) to HDFS 3?

- Kafka Connect HDFS 2 Sink - Confluent community licence
- Kafka Connect HDFS 3 Sink - Confluent enterprise license

Related to: [Need to move small JSON messages from Kafka to HDFS with Kakfa Connect but without using Confluent libs, if not completely free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66840700/need-to-move-small-json-messages-from-kafka-to-hdfs-with-kakfa-connect-but-witho)

Comment: Asking for external libraries is considered off topic - [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a Kafka consumer with Python or any language you want to use, then this consumer with read data coming from Kafka topic as messages, and it will create a file for each message using Linux Hadoop commande (it can be done with Python hadoop package) , then write the data in HDFS files.

Comment: Why not Pyspark / Flink? Also, question did say "Kafka Connect"

Comment: You dont need to write "it works!!" .... As written, this is not "Kafka Connect". I dont know why the questioner accepted your answer over a year later.

Comment: there is other open source kafka connectors to import data (like MongoDB's kafka connector), but the HDFS kafka connector is not open source and requires a license.
Indeed we can create a simple kafka consumer that will read the data from the kafka topic, then insert it into the hdfs file, without need of HDFS connector but we sill use kafka and maybe other open source kafka connectors

Answer (score 1):

The HDFS2 connector **is** open source and free to use with the Community License if you're not using it to offer it as a hosted service, or as I said before, Apache Nifi is a more rich workflow product that works well in the Hadoop ecosystem alongside Kafka. Spark or Flink are often used for this too

Comment: Can the HDFS2 connector write on HDFS 3?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be able to. I've not personally tried though

Comment: From the WebSite: The Kafka Connect HDFS 2 Sink connector allows you to export data from Kafka topics to HDFS 2.x files in a variety of formats and integrates with Hive to make data immediately available for querying with HiveQL.

Comment: That doesn't explicitly say it won't work. For example, Spark 2 still uses HDFS 2.x client libraries, and it can still work with HDFS 3.x servers